Is there only space before the Planck epoch?
In the no boundary proposal, before the Planck epoch or time exist, is there only space?

Firstly, when the universe is treated quantum mechanically, there must be an associated wave function to its evolutionary dynamics. This is the wave function of the universe. What governs said wave function is the debate. But, via the path integral method (as compared to the typical canonical method for quantization), this would correspond to summing over all possible geometries available to the universe (with the geometries being governed by the metric). Of course, if we have a path integral (or just an integral in general), then we need some sort of boundary (or bounds) on the integral. This is the no boundary proposal that says that the wave function should be calculated by summing over all possible geometries that have no boundary in he past (and over typical matter configurations for said geometries).
In doing so, the universe is finite, self contained, and the idea of a singularity is avoided. Therefore, we don't even need to talk about or discuss what was prior to the big bang, we only need to discuss what geometric configurations we must include in the path integral. And, if we want to get philosophical, the geometries include space and time (spacetime geometries), so you could say that time and space configurations are summed over in the no boundary proposal, implying that spacetime is present from the start.
As a concrete example, we can consider the wave function being an path integral over the action with an insertion of some initial spatial geometry $\Psi_0$
\begin{equation}
\Psi = \int [\mathcal{D}g_{\mu\nu}][\mathcal{D}\phi]\:e^{iS[g_{\mu\nu},\phi]/\hbar}\Psi_0.
\end{equation}
For semi-realistic scenarios, the action must include gravity, a scalar field, but also the Gibbons-Hawking-York boundary term. The choice of initial geometry you want to make is the Friendmann-Lemaitre-Roberston-Walker metric (FLRW). To perform the integration however you need to make the saddle point approximation.
